# angualr input not producing the result. in parent conponent

Tags: angular

parent.html

```
   <div>
        <p>form the parent</p>
        <app-child>[value]="from the parent"</app-child>
    </div>
```

---

child.html

```
<p>child works!</p>
<h1>{{value}}</h1>
```

---

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input() value : string;

  constructor() { 

    }



  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }

}
```

angualr input not producing the result. in the parent component. although I have used value in the child component.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using the wrong syntax for passing input values to a component - you're specifying the input value *inside* of the component tags, so Angular will treat it as if you're attempting to pass HTML to the component's `<ng-content>`. Instead, you should specify it as if you're specifying an attribute on an HTML tag:

```html
<div>
  <p>form the parent</p>
  <app-child [value]="from the parent"></app-child>
</div>
```

Additionally, you shouldn't enclose the `value` attribute in square brackets as Angular will treat it as if you have a property in your component's template named `from the parent`. But since there's no such property in your component, it may not render properly. Instead, you should either enclose the attribute's value inside of single-quotation marks or remove the square brackets:

```html
<div>
  <p>form the parent</p>
  <app-child value="from the parent"></app-child>
</div>
```

Or:

```html
<div>
  <p>form the parent</p>
  <app-child [value]="'from the parent'"></app-child>
</div>
```

For more info, check out the [Expression context section of Angular's Template Syntax document](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context).

Answer (score 0):

**value** attribute mentioned out of the app-child elements,  that must be inside the element.

```html
<div>
    <p>form the parent</p>
    <app-child [value]="from the parent"></app-child>
</div>
```